# Maintaining a branch that doesn't contain commits relating to a certain change

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm working on a project with Git and have come to a point where I'd like to break development into two separate branches. The split concerns a simple Change (with a capital C so I can refer back to it later) that affects one isolated part of the codebase -- in one branch, I want the Change to be present; in the other, I don't. The Change is encapsulated in one commit.

The `master` branch, which is where I do all my coding (unless a specific topic comes up) is the branch that I want to contain the Change. I'd like to make a separate branch, `original` (or whatever you want to call it), that does not contain the Change.

`master`, the branch with the Change, will remain the primary, preferred branch: that's the branch I'll keep coding on and that's the branch whose code I'll actually run. I want to keep `original` around just in case I need a version of the code without the aforementioned Change later.

Here's the problem: I'd like to be able to "merge" work from `master` into `original` down the road, but, obviously, only the commits that don't concern the Change.

- If I do a simple `git merge master`, `original` will fast-forward to `master`, introducing the Change I didn't want, right?
- I don't want to develop on `original` and merge to `master`, because `original` is the special case, not `master`.
- I don't want to `cherry-pick` from `master`, because that's going to muddy up my development history.
- I could make a new branch, `develop`, from the commit that introduces the Change in `master`. I could make non-Change-related commits on this branch and easily merge them into `master` or `original`. However, if I make some Change-related commits on `master` and want to merge them into `develop`, then I'll again be unable to safely merge `develop` into `original`, right?

I'd like to know your opinions on how best to proceed.

EDIT: I'm the only person working on this project, so don't rule out a solution because it may mess up other programmers in a collaborative setting. I'm just looking for an **easy-to-use** solution that produces a **clean**, **intuitive** history that captures what these different development histories really are. If no such solution exists, I'll accept one of the answers that get the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about branching off from master to the original branch and then `git revert` the commits which contain the changes you don't want to maintain in the original branch. I guess `git merge` will work then on. Just that the Sum of a few even commits would be null.

Comment: OK, but what if I make more Change-related commits on master in the future? Will I have to revert each time I merge?

Comment: Lets say you have commit hash `e35g5d` in master. You branch off into original and you would have the same commit in original. When you run `git revert` a new commit object will be created which will be an inverse of what is in `e35g5d`. This commit exists only in original and can be maintained only in original branch. Now when you merge master, since the commit with the hash is already present, git would not recreate the commit in the original branch. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: +1: Yes, that does clarify, thank you. I don't love the idea of having to revert commits every time I merge, but this solution works. I'm holding out a little longer for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Let me clarify, once you have reverted the commit in `original` branch you don't have to worry about reverting it again even if the branch master is merged with it!!

Comment: I understand. But if I make more Change-related commits to master, I will have to revert those when I merge, right?

Comment: Gaurav, it took me a day or so to really appreciate your solution. Essentially, you're using a new commit to negate another commit. It's kind of brilliant. It actually serves my purposes quite well, since I probably won't be making too many Change-related commits later on. Still curious to see a more general solution that can gracefully handle several spread-out Change-related commits down the road. But thanks!

Comment: I am glad that I could be helpful.. The other thing which I can think of is more on the lines of Feature Toggles instead of Feature Branching.. Toggling by Abstraction would be a more cleaner approach but am clueless about your problem domain or even the technology used.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I liked the fourth approach:

I would recommend you to create another `hotfix` branch from where you have created `original` branch. Both branches will not contain `Change` related commits and you can safely merge them into `master` and `original` branch.

If you want to merge some `Change` related commits at `master` with `hotfix`, then create `hotfix-with-change` branch from `hotfix` and merge it to there.

When you want to develop a non `Change` related code, that will effect `original` and `master`, do it in `hotfix` and don't forget to update `hotfix-with-change` branch as well.

When you want to develop a `Change` related code, your branch should be `master` branch and if you want to see that commits in `original`, you need to merge that commits with `hotfix-with-change`.

I hope It was clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ogzd. I chose Gaurav's answer because it's just so simple, but I may have to make use of something like this down the road.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's the problem: I'd like to be able to "merge" work from master into
> original down the road, but, obviously, only the commits that don't concern the
> Change.

> I don't want to cherry-pick from master, because that's going to muddy up my
> development history.

If you don't want to merge from master, and you don't want to cherry pick, then `git rebase` is **your only** option.

```
A--B--C  (master)
       \
        X--Y--Z  (original)
```

where `D` `E` `F` are upstream changes

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
       \
        X--Y--Z
```

and `X` `Y` `Z` are undoing the "bad" commits.

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
                 \
                  X'--Y'--Z'
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)